# how to read 2 files line by line and edit each line after being processed

Tags: python, io, fopen

I have a code like the following, which if the line read in the file1 meets my condition, I want to edit/update my file1. Else, I want to edit the line which meets another condition in the file2:

```
with gzip.open('/my/file1.txt.gz', 'r') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"):
        if (str(line[3]) == "C"):
            # edit/update the line from file 1
        else:
            with gzip.open('/my/file2.txt.gz', 'r') as f2:
                for line2 in csv.reader(f2, delimiter="\t"):
                    if line2[0] == line[0]:
                        # edit/update the line2 from file 2
```

Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something among this line:

```
keys = set()
with gzip.open('/my/file1.txt.gz', 'r') as src_file:
    for line in csv.reader(src_file, delimiter="\t"):
        if (str(line[3]) == "C"):
            # edit/update the line from file 1
        else:
            keys.add(line[0])

with gzip.open('/my/file2.txt.gz', 'r') as target_file:
    for line in csv.reader(target_file, delimiter="\t"):
        if line[0] in keys:
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems:

- you are trying to update a read-only file;
- you seem to want to update the file while in the middle of reading it. For a plain-text file, this can be done so long as the replacement string is exactly the same length as what it is replacing. *But* this is a compressed file - I rather think you would corrupt the file.
- you are re-reading the second file every time you want to modify it.

If possible, I would suggest reading the whole works into memory, making the changes, and writing it all back out:

```
import csv, gzip
from collections import defaultdict

def read_gzip(fname):
    with gzip.open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
        return list(incsv)

def write_gzip(fname, data):
    with gzip.open(fname, 'wb') as outf:
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t')
        outcsv.writerows(data)

def main():
    f1, f1_dirty = read_gzip('/my/file1.txt.gz'), False
    f2, f2_dirty = read_gzip('/my/file2.txt.gz'), False

    # make row index on f2
    idx = defaultdict(list)
    for row in f2:
        idx[row[0]].append(row)

    # process files
    for row in f1:
        if row[3] == 'C':
            # modify row data
            f1_dirty = True
        else:
            for other in idx[row[0]]:
                # modify other
                f2_dirty = True

    if f1_dirty: write_gzip('/my/file1.txt.gz', f1)
    if f2_dirty: write_gzip('/my/file2.txt.gz', f2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```